# Id not generated for related entity when saving parent

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to save a Customer to my database and Customer has a couple of relationships. But when I save my Customer, CustomerManagers (One-to-many) doesn't seem to generate their Id's automatically. I get this error:

**"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'AppDB.dbo.CustomerManagers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."**

My Customer class with related data:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerContacts> CustomerContacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerManager> CustomerManagers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerContacts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerManager
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

When I save my Customer, CustomerContacts- and CustomerManagers lists have one item each with Id 0. The first time I did this, it worked, but the related entities got Id 0 in the DB, when they usually starts at 1.
Second time I tried, I got the Insert-error above. I can't figure out why the Id's are not being generated automatically as they usually are. I've tried setting the **[Key]** attribute on the Id's and I've put **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]** on them too, but the same result.
Just to be clear, I'm only adding Customer to the Customers table with the related entities as an item in the lists, and then Saving changes. I've had this working on other entities before and it saved the related entities as it should.

My repository method looks like this:

```
public void Add(Customer entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

and then I have a Commit method on the same repository the just runs `DbSet.SaveChanges();`

Any help is very appriciated!

Martin Johansson

Comment: make sure you have set the Id coulumn to Identity in the database. Sometimes we make such silly mistakes

Comment: I double checked that identity is true when I migrated.